# Why is $|z-a|=\rho$ equivalent to $|z|^2-a(z+\overline{z})=\rho^2-a^2$?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I have some problems to understand the following statement from a book about reflections in poincare half-plane modell:

For $z,\overline{z} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $ a,\rho \in \mathbb{R}$ we have:
$$|z-a|=\rho \quad \text{ equivalent to } \quad  |z|^2-a(z+\overline{z})=\rho^2-a^2$$

My wrong (!) approach (first implication isn't correct):
\begin{aligned}
|z-a|&=\rho\\
\Rightarrow (z-a)^2&=\rho^2\\
\Leftrightarrow  z^2-2az+a^2&=\rho^2&\\
\Leftrightarrow  z^2-z(a+a)&= \rho^2-a^2\\
\Leftrightarrow z^2-z(a+a+bi-bi)&= \rho^2-a^2\\
\Leftrightarrow z^2-z(z+\overline{z})&= \rho^2-a^2
\end{aligned}

It looks fine, except for two points: How do I get $|z|^2$ instead of $|z|$ and $a(z+\overline{z})$ instead of $z(z+\overline z)$?

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: There's an error at the first step of your calculation. You seem to have assumed that $|z-a|^2=(z-a)^2.  That's fine for real numbers, but false for complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $w\bar w=|w|^2$. Then let $w=z-a$. Your first implication is incorrect, be careful.

**ADD** Since $\rho >0$, $|z-a|=\rho \iff |z-a|^2=\rho^2$. Note also that since $a\in\Bbb R$, $\overline{z-a}=\overline z-a $.

Comment: ok thank you, I got it.  Can you some hints how to understand your ADD? I used the statement, but I don't understand, why they are correct.

Comment: @ulead86 If $x,y$ are two non-negative numbers, not both $0$; then $x+y>0$. Thus if $x^2-y^2=0$, we have $x+y=0$ or $x-y=0$. The former is not possible, because of the first observation so we're led to conclude $x=y$. Remember that conjugation preserves sums and products, in the sense that $\overline{z+w}=\overline z+\overline w$ and $\overline{z\cdot w}=\overline z\cdot \overline w$, and $a$ is real if and only if $\overline a =a$.

Comment: thanks again. Now I understood both statements.